# How can I create a div with text that slants?

Tags: html, css

Okay so I've tried this a bunch of ways and want to know what you guys think.  Right now I'm using floats to get this to work but that's preventing me from using flexbox to style the job postings on the right.  Here is what I'm trying to create:

[image]

Here's my css to this point (codepen link at the bottom):

```
.home #slider .item {
    height: 560px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(170, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.home #slider .item #sliderTextContainer {
    height: 560px;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 0;
    -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.home #slider .item #sliderText {
    width:60%;
    align-self: center;
}

.home #slider .item .slide_title {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.home #slider .item .slide_title span {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 135px;
    background-image: url(../../pages/home/img/woosh.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

.home #slider .item .slide_body {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.home #slider .item .btn-lg {
    padding: 12px 30px;
}

.home #slider .item #sliderJobsContainer {
    padding-right: 25px;
    height: 560px;
    background-color: rgb(214,214,214);
    clip-path: polygon(69% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 62% 100%);
}

.home #slider .item #sliderJobs {
    color: black;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mikeoberdick/pen/pxrVKv)

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Look into something thats called skew. [Here's](https://codepen.io/pipozoft/pen/vBwjl) an example.

Comment: @Daniel I just went back and reread and can see how that was not very detailed.  Essentially, I need to 1. Get the bottom border of eac paragraph to stay with the paragraph (:after maybe) and not extend full width to the left.  2.  I need to be able to vertically align the jobs postings div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different method because the gradient was creating a jagged line between the two sections.  Also using one container for all of the content wouldn't allow me to fix the background image on just the left side.

Here's the code:

```
    <div id="slider">
        <div id = "info">
            <div id="infoContainer">
            <p class="slide_title">
            Thinking the way<br /><span>Forward.</span>
            </p>
            <p class="slide_body">
            Palumbo Trucking of Connecticut is a rapidly growing family owned and operated transportation business, dedicated to offering reliable customer service, pristine equipment and highly trained and qualified drivers.
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="./?page=locations">GET A FREE QUOTE</a>  
            </div>  
        </div>

CSS:

<div id = "jobs">
              <a class = "job" href = "/?page=employment">
              <h5>CDL Class A Tractor Trailer Drivers</h5>
              <p>Must have 3 years experience and clean driving record.  Experience with pneumatic tanks a plus, training is available.</p>
              </a>

              <hr>

              <a class = "job" href = "/?page=employment">
              <h5>CDL Class A Dump Trailer Driver</h5>
              <p>3 years experience and clean driving record.</p>
              </a>

              <hr>

              <a class = "job" href = "/?page=employment">
              <h5>Rail Yard Transloader</h5>
              <p>Yard master needed for New Haven and Wallingford locations to transload material from rail cars into pneumatic tanks.  Monday through Saturday, 8-10 hours a day.</p>
              </a>

              <hr>

              <a class = "job" href = "/?page=employment">
              <h5>Fleet PM Service and Trailer Mechanic</h5>
              <p>Full time, various shifts available.</p>
              </a>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.home #slider {
    background: #aa0000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FECA0B;
}

#infoContainer {
    width:60%;
    align-self: center;
}

#info {
    background-image: url('../../pages/home/img/bg-big-head.png');
    height: 560px;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0 80px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(170, 0, 0, 0.4);
    float: left;
    -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 98% 0%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 98% 0%, 85% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.home #slider #info .slide_title {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.home #slider #info .slide_title span {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-left: 135px;
    background-image: url(../../pages/home/img/woosh.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

.home #slider #info .slide_body {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.home #slider #info .btn-lg {
    padding: 12px 30px;
}

#jobs {
    color: black;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    height: 560px;
    background-color: rgb(214,214,214);
}

.job {
    margin-top:40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}

.job:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#jobs a h5 {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#jobs p {
    color: #727272;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#jobs hr {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    margin:0;
}

#jobs hr:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 29%;
}

#jobs hr:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 30%;
}

#jobs hr:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 31%;
}

.job:nth-of-type(1)  {
    margin-top:0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect using a [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) and the [`shape-outside`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/) property.

Demo:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(95deg, rgba(139, 0, 0, 0.8) 60%, grey 60%), url(https://loremflickr.com/2400/768/truck) no-repeat 0 0 /cover;
  height: 560px;
}

.info {
  flex: 1;
}

.jobs {
  width: 40%;
}

.jobs .shape {
  width: 3em;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="info">
  </div>

  <div class="jobs">
    <div class="shape"></div>
    <div class="job">
      <h5>TITLE</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla ipsa iusto eligendi eum libero ipsum, beatae debitis atque praesentium.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="job">
      <h5>TITLE</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla ipsa iusto eligendi eum libero ipsum, beatae debitis atque praesentium.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```